# drop() in pandas doesn't work and doesn't returns error

Tags: merge, drop

so I'm trying to merge two dataframes one with Mean and Median of MODIS land surface temperature I got from images and convert it dataframe, as such :

```
moyenne = np.nanmean(array)
temp_moy17.append(moyenne)
df2017 = pd.DataFrame({'nom':all_files_MOD_2017, 'id':noms_split, 'mods' :mods, 'Moyennes-2017':temp_moy17,'Medianes-2017': temp_med17, 'Nombre-pixel': nbre_pxl})
```

Then, I merge two dataframes, one with my data, the other with the conversion from doy to date, the type of my object is now :

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

my df looks like this :

```
['nom', 'id', 'mods', 'Moyennes-2017', 'Medianes-2017', 'Nombre-pixel', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023']
                                                   nom       id   mods  \
0    K_MOD11A1_061_LST_Night_1km_doy2017105_aid0001...  2017105  Night   
1     K_MOD11A1_061_LST_Day_1km_doy2017105_aid0001.tif  2017105    Day   
2     K_MOD11A1_061_LST_Day_1km_doy2017008_aid0001.tif  2017008    Day   
3    K_MOD11A1_061_LST_Night_1km_doy2017256_aid0001...  2017256  Night   
4     K_MOD11A1_061_LST_Day_1km_doy2017256_aid0001.tif  2017256    Day   
..                                                 ...      ...    ...   
317   K_MOD11A1_061_LST_Day_1km_doy2017142_aid0001.tif  2017142    Day   
318   K_MOD11A1_061_LST_Day_1km_doy2017089_aid0001.tif  2017089    Day   
319  K_MOD11A1_061_LST_Night_1km_doy2017041_aid0001...  2017041  Night   
320   K_MOD11A1_061_LST_Day_1km_doy2017255_aid0001.tif  2017255    Day   
321  K_MOD11A1_061_LST_Night_1km_doy2017349_aid0001...  2017349  Night   

     Moyennes-2017  Medianes-2017  Nombre-pixel        2017        2018  \
0       276.576569     276.419983           152  15/04/2017  15/04/2018   
1       284.126678     282.920013           152  15/04/2017  15/04/2018   
2       277.187805     276.640015           152  08/01/2017  08/01/2018   
3       285.178345     285.150024           152  13/09/2017  13/09/2018   
4       289.639343     290.040009           152  13/09/2017  13/09/2018   
..             ...            ...           ...         ...         ...   
317     296.004547     297.760010           152  22/05/2017  22/05/2018   
318     294.057495     293.880005           152  30/03/2017  30/03/2018   
319     256.785461     256.660004           152  10/02/2017  10/02/2018   
320     288.748291     288.600006           152  12/09/2017  12/09/2018   
321     273.117798     273.000000           152  15/12/2017  15/12/2018   

           2019        2020        2021        2022        2023  
0    15/04/2019  14/04/2020  15/04/2021  15/04/2022  15/04/2023  
1    15/04/2019  14/04/2020  15/04/2021  15/04/2022  15/04/2023  
2    08/01/2019  08/01/2020  08/01/2021  08/01/2022  08/01/2023  
3    13/09/2019  12/09/2020  13/09/2021  13/09/2022  13/09/2023  
4    13/09/2019  12/09/2020  13/09/2021  13/09/2022  13/09/2023  
..          ...         ...         ...         ...         ...  
317  22/05/2019  21/05/2020  22/05/2021  22/05/2022  22/05/2023  
318  30/03/2019  29/03/2020  30/03/2021  30/03/2022  30/03/2023  
319  10/02/2019  10/02/2020  10/02/2021  10/02/2022  10/02/2023  
320  12/09/2019  11/09/2020  12/09/2021  12/09/2022  12/09/2023  
321  15/12/2019  14/12/2020  15/12/2021  15/12/2022  15/12/2023  

[322 rows x 13 columns]
```

I want to drop 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022, 2023 columns but it doesn't work.

I tried :

```
df2017.drop(columns=['2018'])

df2017.drop(['2018'], axis=1)

date_correspondance.drop(labels = ['2018'])
```

with and without indexes, with and without inplace = True. I don't have any error it just doesn't work. When I tried without axis=1 I get "[Columns] not found in axis".

```
print(df2017.columns.tolist())
```

returns me my columns just as expected :

```
['nom', 'id', 'mods', 'Moyennes-2017', 'Medianes-2017', 'Nombre-pixel', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023']
```

```
df2017.index
```

returns :

```
Int64Index([  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   8,   9,  10,
            ...
            312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321],
           dtype='int64', length=320)
```

```
print(type(df2017['2018']))
```

returns

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I tried to force the index name of my df because 2018 columns are series like this :

```
index = ['nom', 'id', 'mods', 'Moyennes-2017', 'Medianes-2017', 'Nombre-pixel', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022', '2023']
date_correspondance.index = index
```

but it returns, does it mean that somehow my df is  :

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 366 elements, new values have 13 elements
```

I tried to convert it to dt.datetime.strptime, it doesn't work because it's Series ...

Thanks in advance for your help

I explained above what I tried